# MongoDB Documents : Find number of Repetitions and Sort In Ascending Order

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I'm working on an agent that's supposed get data from **MongoDB**, iterate through it, and then find the keys which have the same values, and sort that list in ascending order. Basically, find out how many repetitions there are in the documents from Mongo, and then sort it.

So I've gotten to the part where I get repetitions in the data, and count them, but I'm stuck with getting the ascending order part.

---

---

The code for getting documents out of **mongodb** and processing it is as follows.

```
function matchRoomAndAgent() {
var url = 'mongodb://192.168.10.10:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    db.collection("whiteboardRooms").find({}).toArray(function (err, res) {
        var roomsArray = [];
        var count = {};
        var temp_count = {};
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        db.close();
        // roomsArray.push(res);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            roomsArray.push(res[i]);
            // console.log('agentId:  '+ res[i][agentId].agentId);
        }

        // console.log(roomsArray);

        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) //supposed to use length of roomsArray
        {
            var currentAgent = roomsArray[i].agentId;
            for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++)
            {
                if (roomsArray[j].agentId == currentAgent)
                {
                    count[j] = (count[j] || 0) + 1;
                    temp_count[j] = count[j];                     
                }
            }
            console.log(temp_count);
        }
```

---

Also please find attached, a sample pic of the mongodb documents.

[MongoDB Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06irl.png)

Please let me know if you require more information, and I'll do my best to get it. I'm kind of a noob at programming. Sorry!

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Could you edit the post to include 2 sample docs?  I suspect the aggregation framework will do what you need without all the extra javascript coding.   Faster, too...

Comment: Hi Buzz, I've edited it to included the documents

Comment: OK, so when you say "the keys which have the same values" do you mean the agentId field?   And then sorted ascending by that key?   Given your screen shot as the input, what's your desired output?   Is it 3 rows, one for " ", one for "3", and one for "test id"?

Comment: I'm trying to see how many records have the same agentId. Like for agent 3 : 2 repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

At some point you might want to limit the material being grouped, for example by `lastUpdateTime` between two timestamps and you don't want to drag all that out of the DB just to throw it away.  Here's the general shape of the solution:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$match: {agentID: {$ne: " "}}}   // guessing this is noise so filter out
  // other $match could be used here to further shrink the data...
  ,{$group: {_id:"$agentID", n:{$sum:1}}}
  ,{$match: {n: {$gt:1}}}  // ignore non-dupes
  ,{$sort: {_id: 1}} // and finally sort.
              ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured out the answer to my own problem. Its pretty much got nothing to do with **MongoDB**. 
I basically had an array called *roomsArray* which contained objects. I used *groupBy* and *map* to project these objects to a format I wanted, and then used *sort* as I would an array, using its length to get the count.

---

I should have used *groupBy()* and *map()* with *sort()* to get the values I needed.

```
var groupBy = function (array, key) {
            return array.reduce(function(acc,val){
                (acc[val[key]] = acc[val[key]] || []).push(val);
                return acc;
            }, {});
        };
        var result = groupBy(roomsArray, 'agentId');
        // console.log(result);
        var mapped = Object.keys(result).map(function(x){
            return { agentId : x, rooms: parseInt(result[x].length)}
        });
        // console.log(mapped);
        var sorted = mapped.sort((a,b) => a.rooms - b.rooms);
        console.log(sorted);
```